# C#: Scroll/AutoResize child controls in custom control, slow repaint

Tags: c#, scroll, resize, custom-controls, scrollbar

I'm currently writing an custom control which has to hold child control and have to support scrolling and autorisze.
Autoscrolling is not possible because my control is fully selfpainted an only a part of the control should be scrolled.

Now the the repainting of the Controls is extrem slow, especialy with textbox and buttoncontrols with systempainting. Deactivating systempainting (`TextBox.BorderStyle = Borderstyle.Fixed`) helps, but the control should also support this. Using `SetRedraw` and updating the controls afterward doesn't help, because the textbox systemdraw is ignored and the textbox looks ugly. Refreshing my whole control or using `` `RedrawWindow `` slows the painting down again.

i also already tried to suspend my control and child controls layout without success.

Does anybody know how to speedup the childcontrol painting like AutoScrolling.

My CustomControl has the Style `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer`.

The ChildControl bound is changed on (MyControl)Resize and (ScrollBar)OnValueChanged.

Using a Timer helps a little, but i don't know if this is realy the right solution.

**EDIT :**
I have found the problem, aufter reactivating `SetRedraw` and `Refresh`, `OnPaint` fires 38 times with 37 Controls. Is the any workaround?

Comment: Did you try to use the double buffer property?

Comment: like you can see i already set DoubleBuffer in set style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to speed it up, by adding a custom flag which tells me if the OnPaint is fired by my control or by a child control. If my control fires the event i draw my controls content to a bitmap and just blit it for the childcontrols.

Answer (score 1):

It gets slow with that many controls, 37 of them is just rather a lot.  For comparison, Microsoft Outlook uses about 50 windows, you've got 38 for just a control.  It gets extra slow because of transparency effects on those controls.  The OnPaint() method runs so often to provide the background pixels of the controls.  You can't always fix that, a Button for example is going to let its parent draw the background even if it is not transparent.  Controls are very convenient but they are *not* cheap.

Only one way to really get ahead here: stop using so many controls and stop trying to support transparency.  Not sure what you use, but a Label for example is especially wasteful.  Using TextRenderer.DrawText in your OnPaint method also can draw a label, minus the cost of a Control.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i wanted to use controls, because i didn't want to write my own textbox, by like it seems there isn't another way

Comment: Don't rewrite TextBox, it is quite untrivial.  Pick the low hanging fruit first, labels, picture boxes, panels.  Simplify the user interface, no user can get dozens of text boxes filled without making a mistake or nodding off anyway.